# string as name of new class variable

Tags: c#, sql

I'm having trouble figuring this out, I want to put the name I send with the method as name of the new class variable I'm trying to make. This is what I have now.

```
public void GetDier(string naam) 
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM [Dieren] WHERE Diersoort = '" + naam + "'";
    sqlconn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn);
    SqlDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    string diernaam = DR.GetString(1);
    int currency = DR.GetInt32(2);
    int TPnodig = DR.GetInt32(3);
    Dieren naam = new Dieren(diernaam, TPnodig, currency);
}
```

I want make the string naam, as the new name of the new dier as I'm trying to do in the piece of code above.

Comment: Never use string concatentation for building SQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a more secured method to get the data from db:

```
public Dieren GetDier(string naam)
        {
            var con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Yourconnection"].ToString();
Dieren naamValue= new Dieren();
            using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(con))
            {
                string oString ="SELECT * FROM [Dieren] WHERE Diersoort = @Diersoort";
                SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(oString, myConnection);
                oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Diersoort", naam);           
                myConnection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (oReader.Read())
                    {    
                        naamValue.naam= oReader["naam"].ToString();                       
                    }

                    myConnection.Close();
                }               
            }
            return naamValue;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a variable as name of another variable. And honestly, that doesn't make sense. The name of a variable is only useful to you as a programmer, not for the end result of the code.

Also be aware that your SQL is vulnerable to SQL injection. Always use parameterized queries!

Comment: The problem is that I want to take out every Dier I have in my Dieren table and add them to the class. This was the only way I could think of, do you maybe have another solution to this?

Comment: So you want to stuff them in a list or a dictionary?